# Change "Quoted-printable" encoding to "utf-8"

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x

I am trying to read email with imaplib. I get this mail body:

```
=C4=EE=E1=F0=FB=E9 =E4=E5=ED=FC!
```

That is `Quoted-printable` encoding.
I need to get `utf-8` from this. It should be `Добрый день!`

I googled it, but it is too messy with Python's versions. It is already unicode in Python 3, I cann't use `.encode('utf-8')` here.

How can I change this to `utf-8`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`quopri` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) can convert those bytes to an unencoded byte stream. You need to then decode those from whatever character set they're in, then encode back to `utf-8`.

```
>>> b = quopri.decodestring('=C4=EE=E1=F0=FB=E9 =E4=E5=ED=FC')
>>> print(b.decode('windows-1251'))
Добрый день
```

Comment: what about python3?

Comment: @JamesTan this answer *is* for Python3. I just tried it again in Python 3.6 and it works fine. Are you having trouble?